# How do I write a trait to mutate an integer in place?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a trait for integers that adds a value to themselves.

My failing attempt so far:

```rust
impl TryAdd for u128 {
    fn try_add(self, rhs: Self) -> Result<Self, ProgramError> {
        self.checked_add(rhs).ok_or(SomeError::BadError.into())
    }
    fn try_self_add(mut self, rhs: Self) -> ProgramResult {
        self = self.try_add(rhs)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The first function works as expected, returning a new integer with rhs added. The second function currently doesn't work.

What I'd like it to do:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_self_add() {
    let x = 10;
    let y = 2;
    x.try_self_add(y).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(x, 12);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please make your example self-contained, see http://sscce.org/. Also try to avoid terms like "it doesn't work", instead, write what behavior you expect and what you got instead, in a concrete manner (e.g. a compilation error).

Comment: [`AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) from the standard library is quite similar to what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `try_self_add` you modify copy of the value instead of the value itself, so it is expected behaviour (that is also why `x` in test do not need to be `mut`). What you really want is:

```rust
fn try_self_add(&mut self, rhs: Self) -> ProgramResult {
    *self = self.try_add(rhs)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

With such alteration [it works as expected](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78c1dcc21f5549d97a1740f499f3994d).

Comment: God this is embarassing... forgot to put & in front of the mut. Thanks a ton for your answer - and for the example, super helpful.